# Nativescript File Picker Build errors while compile

Tags: android, ios, android-service, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am developing of Sleep alarm.
And I want to select `*.mp3` from **sdcard** for alarm sound.

But `nativescript` plugin "[nativescript-file-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-mediafilepicker)" is not working, or error.
there is no documentation of usage,

Comment: What is "not working, or error" ? Show us what you have done and and what the logs might look like

Comment: Keep in mind that the nativescript-file-picker plugin is not migrated for NativeScript 3.0.0 so it would work only with NativeScript 2.5.x (as of today

Comment: I have done.
By creating new Nativescript Plugin.